# How does this work in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var temp = temp || {};
```

In the above syntax temp is created if it is not already exist otherwise it will refer to the variable which was already created. Just I am curious that how does this work. I think right side of expression should return true if temp exists but it is creating an object. How does this work. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: See the _Logical OR `||` operator_ on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Basically, in `expr1 || expr2`, if `expr1` is truthy, it gets returned, otherwise `expr2` gets returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declare temp and use it on the other side of expression, it value is undefined, so, for example, if you say `var temp = temp;` you will see that `temp` is undefined.

You are using the expression `||` (OR) so it is a boolean expression. Since `temp` is not declared before and it is `undefined` this side will be "false" and the return is the other side.

Its simplyfied version to `var temp = (temp == undefined || temp == false)  ? {} : temp;`

Answer (score 5):

`a || b` uses the logical OR operator, which evaluates `a`, and if `a` is truthy, it evaluates to `a`. Otherwise, `b` is returned.

If `temp` isn’t already declared, `var temp` has “already” declared it by the time it’s used in `temp = ""` (variable declarations are function-wide in JavaScript). If it *is* already declared, no problem; redeclaration is valid in JavaScript, and doesn’t affect the existing value of the variable.

“Truthy” here means “not falsy”. Things that are falsy in JavaScript:

- `false`
- `0` (and `-0` for that matter)
- `NaN`
- `""`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

you could check if the variable exists in javascript using this:

```
if (typeof temp === 'undefined') {
// temp is undefined
//create variable temp
// your code here
}
else{
//temp exists
//your code here
}
```